# Using a list in excel to replace words in a word document - need to select and paste not REPLACE

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I've got a spreadsheet with two column. One with lookup words and the other with replacement words. This code works through the lookup woods column and searches for them one at a time in Word. When it finds a match, it replaces it with the corresponding entry in the replacement words column.

The code is below and there's a lot of it.

I've kludged this together from many online resources..it's franken code and I'm sorry.

Right now

```
Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object, itm As Range
    Dim ObjData As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim strText
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\keith.docm"
        .Activate

        With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            '.ClearFormatting
            '.Replacement.ClearFormatting

            For Each itm In ws.Range("Checklist1[PolicyIdentifier]").Cells

                .Text = itm.Value2                          'Find all strings in col F
                strText = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2
                ObjData.SetText strText
                mClipboard.SetClipboard (itm.Offset(, 1).Value2)

                    .Replacement.text= "^c"



                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False

                    .Execute replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)


            Next
        End With

          With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            '.ClearFormatting
            '.Replacement.ClearFormatting

            For Each itm In ws.Range("Checklist1[QuestionIdentifer]").Cells

                .Text = itm.Value2                          'Find all strings in col I
                strText = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2
                mClipboard.SetClipboard (itm.Offset(, 1).Value2)
                    .Replacement.Text = "^c"



                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False

                    .Execute replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)

            Next
        End With



        '.Quit SaveChanges:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Right now it when it runs the text from excel loses it's formatting when it's sent to word.

What I think I'd like to do is, instead of search and replace to do a search and PASTE - so I can keep my formatting.

But I am at a loss as to how to do it.

The replace.text = "^c" is already pulling from the clipboard - everythings is getting there okay. But I want to paste it outright ..

or if ya'll know a way to get search/replace to work while keeping my source formatting...I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code saves a value to the clipboard without any formatting. Just copy instead, `itm.Offset(, 1).Copy`. (Delete `strText = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2` and `mClipboard.SetClipboard (itm.Offset(, 1).Value2)` and `.Replacement.Text = "^c"`).

To paste in Word use either `Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False` or `Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting`. [PasteExcelTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pasteexceltable) and [PasteAndFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pasteandformat) are Word methods, so you'll need to add a reference. Open Excel. Open the Visual Basic Editor. Click Tools > References. Scroll down and select "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library."

Use a [loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/doloop-statement) instead of `.Execute replace:=2`.

```vb
    Do
        .Execute
        If .Found = True Then Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    Loop Until .Found = False
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.